# Probability of having picked every item from the set at least once after n turns, while picking 3 per turn

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, inclusion-exclusion, coupon-collector

Let's say I have a set of 100 items. Each turn, I pick three items at random, note which ones I've picked, and put them back. What is the probability I've picked every item at least once after $n$ turns? The only statement I can make right now is that $n \geq \frac{100}{3}$ in order for the probability to be non-zero.

Comment: Presumably, you mean you choose three distinct items at random.

Comment: This is a case for inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Yes. Included both.

Comment: Since you know that it is inclusion-exclusion, what do you need to use inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: I don't know that it is inclusion-exclusion. In fact, I don't know what that is.  But I'm quick to trust people so I added it as a tag.

Comment: Oh, I see you added that tag to the question after my comment. Sorry. This question is very hard if you don't know inclusion-exclusion.